# Is this a correct class-based-django-view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my project i have a page that displays a form where the User inputs some irrelevant(for the moment project name) and a host/ip-address. When he hits the scan button he makes a post request.
In the current moment i get that ip address and im trying to 'banner-grab' the running services on that ip/host and render the results to the page. In the code below i got that working but as im litteraly using django for the first time i think that my aproach is really bad cause all of my code( for grabbing the banner etc ) is in the POST function in my class-based-view.**So question is can i do this in a better way? Maybe write that bannerGrab() function somewere else and, if form is valid just call the function in the POST method...**

````
class NewProject(View):
    # Reusable across functions
    form_class = ProjectData
    template_name = 'projectRelated/create_project.html'
    ports = [20, 21, 22, 23, 80, 3306]

    def get(self, request):
        # redundant to use it like this
        # form = ProjectData()
        form = self.form_class
        context = {
            'form': form
            # this is a context variable that i can use in my html page. like this <h3> {{ context.var }} </h3>
            # context = {
            #     'context.var': 'This will render in the html'
            # }
        }
        print('Get method accessed!')
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    # TODO: Find a better way to show and store ports
    #       Store the results in JSON

    # TODO: Store to  JSON by choice. Not all code in POST method!!!
    def post(self, request):
        list_of_services = []
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            _target = form.cleaned_data['target']
            host_to_ip = ''
            # project_from_input = form.cleaned_data['project_name']
            print(_target)
            for port in self.ports:
                try:
                    error_message = 'Couldn\'t connect. Try another subnet!'
                    socket_obj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    # if connection is established result is 0.
                    # 0.5 seconds timeout. If subnet isn't reachable
                    socket_obj.settimeout(2)
                    if _target.isalpha():
                        # if user's input was alphanumeric convert to an ip address
                        host_to_ip = socket.gethostbyname(_target)
                        result = socket_obj.connect_ex((host_to_ip, port))
                    else:
                        # user's input was an IP address.
                        result = socket_obj.connect_ex((_target, port))
                    # If port is HTTP we need to make a request to get data!
                    if port == 80 and result == 0:
                        # in order to get an answer from the server we need to make a legitimate request to him.
                        bytes_to_send = str.encode("HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")
                        # send our request FIRST.
                        socket_obj.send(bytes_to_send)
                        # grab the banner after server answers
                        banner = socket_obj.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                        for service in banner.split('\n'):
                            if 'Server:' in service:
                                list_of_services.append(service + ' running at port : ' + str(port))
                                socket_obj.close()
                    # an established connection returns 0 !
                    if result == 0:
                        banner = socket_obj.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                        banner_with_port = banner + ' running at port : ' + port
                        list_of_services.append(banner_with_port)
                        socket_obj.close()
                except Exception as ex:
                    print('Exception -> ' + str(ex))
                finally:
                    socket_obj.close()
                    # After button Run-Scan is pressed clear the form without reloading the page.
                    form = self.form_class
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'list_of_services': list_of_services,
                'error_message': error_message,
                'target_input': _target,
            }
            print('POST METHOD ACCESSED!')
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)```
````

Comment: I guess web and networking tags were redundant. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure, moving all that logic into another method will make the code much cleaner. The post method should usually be concerned with parsing the form data, validating it and returning the response.

You could just make another method inside the NewProject class. Or you can create a new class called BannerManager and move the logic there. But I don't see a point in creating a new class unless you have more place where you are working with sockets, banners etc.

Comment: Thanks Kolev! I was thinking of putting this code into the forms.py ( ProjectData class ) but i thought it was stupid enough so i asked here. You really helped me here . Thanks a lot